# Wait for FileReader slice blob entirely

Tags: javascript, html, cryptojs

I'm trying to read files data with FileReader API, and I read so many questions with this same problem and tried to implement their solutions, but for some bug in my code (maybe), it keep doing wrong result. To avoid crashing the browser when the file is too large (more than 15MB) I decided to start using the 'slice' method. But the problem is that as the FileReader onload event is async, I get at the part of the code where it should have the completed buffer ready to soon, when it's still incomplete. And I can't make everything inside the onload event, because it have only part of the total buffer. Here is my code:

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) 
{
    var file = window.files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onload = function(evt) {           
        window.bits.push(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(evt.target.result, window.password)); 
    };
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

function encrypt()
{
    window.files = document.getElementById('encrypt-input').files;
    if (!window.files.length) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return;
    }
    window.password = $('#key').val();
    window.bits = [];
    var startByte = 0;              
    var endByte = 0;
    while(startByte <= document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].size - 1)
    {       
        endByte = startByte + 1024;
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
        startByte = endByte;
        if (startByte >= document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].size)
        {
            alert('Here I want the total array length:' + window.bits.length);      
        }   
    }   
            alert('Here I want the total array length:' + window.bits.length);          
}
```

As you can see right above, I tried this:

```
    if (startByte >= document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].size)
    {
        alert('Here I want the total array length:' + window.bits.length);      
    }
```

But I still getting the length 0 for some reason. How can I process the entire buffer when using the slice method? Another secondary question is: inside the onload event, I call a synchronous function 'CryptoJS.AES.encrypt', but as this event is async, I was expecting that the browser won't freeze while processing the buffer into this event. Is there any way that I can implement something to avoid freezing the browser while processing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `reader.readAsDataURL()` is asynchronous. You have to pass a callback to `readBlob` which is called when it is finished:

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte, done) {
    ...
    reader.onload = function(evt) {           
        window.bits.push(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(evt.target.result, window.password));
        done();
    };
    ...
}

function encrypt() {    
    ...
    var startByte = 0;              
    var endByte = 0;
    var callback = function(){
        alert('Here I want the total array length:' + window.bits.length);
    };
    while(startByte <= document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0].size - 1) {
        endByte = startByte + 1024;
        (function(startByte, endByte, newCallback){
            callback = function(){
                readBlob(startByte, endByte, newCallback);
            };
        })(startByte, endByte, callback);
        startByte = endByte;
    }
    callback(); // run the chain
}
```

There is simply no other sensible way, because JavaScript doesn't have a `sleep` function.

Comment: Didn't worked :(... If I copy/paste your example, the browser freezes like a infinity loop, if I put `startByte = endByte` outside the callback function, it gets called and show me the alert everytime the onload is fired, and not only when completed... Looks like the if expression is not correct...

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure what you wanted to do. The problem is that some of the execution is asynchronous, and because of that a chain of callbacks has to be built.

Comment: My code is exactly like yours, but the readBlob never gets called ;\... This is a strange thing for me, because the API provide a slice method, but for some reason, we can't reach the complete buffer with easy coding. I think is a normal behavior process the file in slices but execute a function with the complete buffer. I can't understand why is so hard to do this...

Comment: You said the readAsDataURL is asynchronous. There is another method synchronous?

Comment: It's probably easier when some helper functions are writting. There is no synchronous FileReader function that I know of. I've added an IIFE, maybe this was the issue.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but I'm almost giving up. The code inside `(function(startByte, endByte){` don't gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to do that the "sync way". You can find the documentation here -> http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#FileReaderSync.
I have also discovered this library - FileReader.js (http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/) that not only makes your life much easier when it comes to use FileReader, but also has already built in options to use the sync methods to synchronously read the files.
Sorry to not being able to post some example code rigth now! Hope it helped, anyway!